# Checking for multiple values Python MySQL

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to execute a query using Python however, when trying to get the email and password the user has input into the website, it returns "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'dsfs'' at line 1" (dsfs being the password which is incorrect)

```
@login_blueprint.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'email' in request.form:
        try:
            email = request.form['email']
            password = request.form['password']
            database = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=DBHost,
                user=DBUser,
                passwd=DBPass,
                database=DB
            )
            cursor = database.cursor()
            query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email, password) = %s, %s"
            values = (email, password)
            cursor.execute(query, values)
            cursor.fetchall()
            return render_template('dashboard.html', email=email)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
            return jsonify(result='that account does not exist')
    return render_template('login.html')
```

When I register details it works fine and inputs the data into the MySQL table.

```
@register_blueprint.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'email' in request.form:
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        database = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=DBHost,
            user=DBUser,
            passwd=DBPass,
            database=DB
        )
        cursor = database.cursor()
        query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        values = (email, password)
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        database.commit()
        return jsonify(result='account created, proceed to login')
    return render_template('register.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change SQL syntax:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %s AND password = %s"
values = (email, password)
cursor.execute(query, values)
cursor.fetchall()
```

And empty value of fetchall() method wont raise any exception, it returns empty tuple